# How to setup GitKraken with my own server

Tags: git, ssh-keys, gitkraken

Hi following a guide (https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server) I'm able to use git with the repository on my server from command line. 
I installed GitKraken and i opened the repository dir on my pc. It recognize the remote repository but I'm not able to pull/push. Clicking on Edit Origin, i get:

```
Name : origin
Pull URL: ssh://user@hostname/home/user/project-1.git
Push URL: ssh://user@hostname/home/user/project-1.git
```

The error of Gitkraken is:

```
Configured SSH key is an invalid format. 
Please ensure that your key is valid and is an RSA-type key
```

I already tryed to use

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 5):

Just solved this problem on windows:

1. You need to use a local ssh agent (Pageant).
2. On Settings/Authentication check "Use local agent".
3. Be sure to have Pageant installed and running on your computer. (Installed with PuTTY).
4. Add your key to Pageant.

I don't know how to solve it on Unix, but you have to search around for `localSSHAgent`.